# selenium: no such element: Unable to locate element by using xpath for espncricket

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm having some difficulty, I want to find the Commentary button and then click it.

This is the website:

```
from selenium import webdriver

button1= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-container']/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]")

button1.click()
```

But some problems happen, how to slove this ? I tried to select it by class name before, but class name is not unique and hard to locate.

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='main-container']/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]"}
> (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: can you share page URL or relevant HTML ?

Comment: https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/carlton-series-2000-01-61080/australia-vs-west-indies-1st-match-65601/full-scorecard

Comment: okay I have tested this with Explicit waits, do check out below and let me know if you run into any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay try with below `xpath` :

```
//div[text()='Commentary']/..
```

**in code :**

```
button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Commentary']/..")
button1.click()
```

**or with explicit waits :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/carlton-series-2000-01-61080/australia-vs-west-indies-1st-match-65601/full-scorecard")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Commentary']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```